# uses and procedure syntax errors

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I was trying to understand how to use units in my main 'modules test unit'. they are 'module1.pas', and 'module2.pas'.
This is a console program and I would like for both units to be displayed and used in my main unit modules_test:

```
program modules_test;

uses
  SysUtils, module1, module2;

procedure modules_display;
begin
  module1;
  module2;
end;

end.
```

here's unit module1:

```
unit module1;

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils;

implementation

begin
  writeln('this is module 1....');

end.
```

And module2:

```
unit module2;

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils;

implementation

begin
  writeln('this is module 2....');

end.
```

As I'm fairly certain that I'm missing a few things, as well as the errors I get, what would I need to use for this to execute properly?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ip76Nc6q ?

Comment: thank you. I knew I was missing something.

Comment: I fear what you might be missing is your Delphi manual. What reference were you reading when you wrote that code?

Comment: it was just a simple test program I wanted to run. I'm slowly learning delphi and have most of the books I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
program modules_test;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses 
  SysUtils, module1, module2;

procedure modules_display;
begin
  module1.Test;  // Fully qualify the name of the procedure
  module2.Test;
end;

begin
  modules_display;
  ReadLn;
end.
```

---

```
unit module1;

interface

// Declare a procedure that can be called from outside of this unit
procedure Test;  

implementation

uses
  // Unit references that are exclusively used in the implementation section
  Classes, SysUtils; 

// This is the implementation of the procedure
procedure Test;
begin
  writeln('this is module 1....');
end;

end.
```

---

```
unit module2;

interface

// Declare a procedure that can be called from outside of this unit
procedure Test;

implementation

uses
  // Unit references that are exclusively used in the implementation section
  Classes, SysUtils;

// This is the implementation of the procedure
procedure Test;
begin
  writeln('this is module 2....');
end;

end.
```

See some documentation, [Programs and Units](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Programs_and_Units).

Comment: In this example, `uses Classes, SysUtils;` should be moved to the `implementation` sections of `module1` and `module2`, as there is nothing declared in the `interface` sections that depend on those units.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, yes that is a sane thing to do.